# Problem with UV mapping (single face dis formed)

Tags: uv

I, in my opinion would not label my self as an advanced person with blender, so there may be something I am not doing or missing. I was trying to make a model when I stumbled upon a problem with UV mapping. I originally was not surprised as I often mess up UV mapping in some shape or form but this time it was different, a solid face with no brakes was being dis formed and i had no clue why. It cant be the seams because its one face, and I set the scale to 1,1,1. I still have yet to fix this problem or what or why its happening. [image: the face and the respective UV mapping]I would still consider my self new to blender and if anyone has a solution to my problem please inform me of any mistakes I have made. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use a different operator with N-gons

N-gons are very handy, but they come at the cost of not having a precisely defined topology between the vertices. Blender is struggling to recognize the shape of the surface, the proportion of each branch, with the **Unwrap** operator due to the algorithm that's behind it.

I'll suggest to simply use another operator for this specific task, for example the **Smart UV Project** operator:

[image]

Comment: I tried it and it work, however should I use smart UV unwrap for the rest or alternate.

Comment: There is usually no need to use the same operator for all. Choose the one that best suit your needs.